# Where did Raistlin get the Dragon Orb he uses to talk to Dalamar?

Tags: dragonlance

I'm in the process of re-reading all the Dragonlance novels. In *Dragons of Winter Night*,

> Raistlin gains control of a Dragon Orb.

Then, in *Time of the Twins*,

> Raistlin says he's given the orb to Lorac and taught him how to use it.

But now, in *War of the Twins*,

> Raistlin pulls out the Orb to talk to Dalamar across time. How did he get it back? Did I miss something, and he didn't actually leave it with Lorac?

Comment: Discussion in comments about spoilers has now been [archived in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60724/discussion-on-question-by-mycodesucks-where-did-raistlin-get-the-dragon-orb-he-u), and I've edited the title according to [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11035/31394) well-received meta answer. **Please see [the associated meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11032/31394) before making any changes to the title of this question.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the problem is that there's time travel involved. In *Time of the Twins*, it is [as Fistandantilus](http://www.dragonlanceforums.com/archive/index.php/t-10448.html), in the past, that Raistlin teaches Lorac to use the orb, which Lorac had stolen:

> "I have walked these halls as Fistandantilus for months now. These last few weeks I have traveled to all the Towers of High Sorcery - those still standing, that is - to study and learn. I have been with Lorac, in the elven kingdom, and taught him to use the dragon orb - a deadly gift, for one as weak and as vain as he. It will snare him, later on."
>   -Raistlin Majere, *Time of the Twins*, chapter 9

*[Dragons of a Fallen Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_a_Fallen_Sun)* details that Lorac stole the orb in the "[Song of Lorac](http://www.lunasreview.com/song/lorac/)":

> Comes to the Tower Lorac Caladon, King of the Silvanesti,
>   To take his Test in magic before the closing of the Tower.
>   In his Test, one of the dragon orbs,
>   fearful of falling into the hands
>   of the Kingpriest and his minions,
>   speaks to Lorac.
>   “You must not leave me here in Istar.
>   If you do, I will be lost and the world will perish.”
>   Lorac obeys the voice of the dragon orb,
>   hides the orb away.
>   carries it with him from the Tower,
>   carries the orb back to Silvanesti,
>   holds the orb in secret, hugging his secret to him,
>   never telling anyone.

In *Dragons of Winter Night*, Raistlin reacquires the orb from a mad Lorac.

Comment: So, when he goes back in time, does he take his conquered orb with him?  Does it mean that there are two versions of that orb at that moment? Time travel hurts my brain, lmao.

Comment: Likely there were 2 orbs: one, from the Tower of High Sorcery, that Raistlin/Fistandantilus gave to Lorac (Fistandantilus gave the same orb to Lorac in unaltered timeline). The other (taken from Lorac later in time) he kept with himself and used it to contact Dalamar,

Comment: Also, now that I'm looking at the passage again, it doesn't explicitly say he gave the orb to Lorac, only that he taught him to use it. Hrm.

Comment: It is possible that he did not give the orb to Lorac himself. Lorac was an adept mage (although failed to control the orb) and could have obtained the orb by other means

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: Lorac acquired the orb from the Tower of High Sorcery.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, yes, in *Winter Night*, he does get it from the Tower. However, time travel being involved at this point, It threw me off.

Answer (score 7):

### There were Five Dragon orbs on Krynn.

**One** was obtained by Lorac before the Cataclysm in the Tower of High Sorcery. In unaltered timeline, Fistandantilus taught him to use it, as Raistlin travelled through time, he assumed Fistandantilus's identity and repeated all his deeds, including this one.

In the time of the War Of The Lance (~358 AC), it was the same orb subdued by Raistlin and taken from dying Lorac. Later he kept it and took with him to the past, creating an alternate timeline, when both orbs were present: one with Lorac, and another (aged copy of the same one) - with Raistlin.

**The second** was captured by Laurana during the battle at the Ice wall (covered in detail in *Dragons of the Highlord Skies*, only referenced in *Dragons Of The Winter Night*. Then it was a constant cause of disputes and quarrels, until

> destroyed by Tasslehoff.

**The third** was discovered

> by Laurana in the Tower of High Clerist at the end of the book.

The fourth is believed to be destroyed in Cataclysm.
The fifth is only mentioned in context of creation. It's fate and whereabouts are unknown.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I'm not asking about the other orbs, only the one specifically conquered by Raistlin. How can he have his orb, if he gave it to Lorac?

Comment: Rephrased the explanation of the first orb to be a proper answer.